# why do i get this error "Unknown host http:80"?

Tags: eclipse, http, blackberry

i'm developing an application for blackbery, i'm displaying a webpage using Eclipse and net.rim.device.api.browser.field.* api when i click a submit buttom in a form i get this error "Unknown host http:80", can anyone helpme?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about Blackberries, but it looks like you're entering a URL where your program is only expecting a host name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like form on the web page is not properly set up, causing the post action to post to an invalid URL.  It would help if you included the app code and the form HTML.

Comment: Marc, i get this error when i use the net.rim.device.api.browser.field.* api, when i call the browser or use the net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.* api it works... thank you for your help... i decide to update my BB to the version 5.0 now i can use net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.* api without any problem

Answer (score 0):

In [this 2005 forum thread](http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-legacy-device-discussion/4914-7100g-http-error-400-unknown-host-help.html) people complain about getting that kind of error on their Blackberries.

I'm on the server side and I can see some Proxy servers trying to access my server with either HTTP/1.0 and no HTTP_HOST (which my app requires) or using the wrong HTTP_HOST.
For example, I am getting requests for widgets.twimg.com , www.google-analytics.com , servedby.jumpdisplay.com . My server doesn't host those domains so the response is obviously not any of the sites on the server, and instead I'm giving back an error.

So, it might be that your Blackberry is not providing the right HTTP_HOST to the server (or none at all) and the server doesn't know what to do with it.

To me, that's Blackberry (or whatever proxy that might exist between you and the server) 's fault.